# How to change the shape of Floating Action Button (FAB) on android?

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes, floating-action-button, android-shapedrawable

In our android app we need to create a floating action button which isn't the default circle but a square with with three rounded corners. The fab looks like in the image below:

[image]

I managed to create such a form but don't know how to apply it to my fab, or if it's even possible. The xml file for the shape looks like this:

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
    <corners
      android:topLeftRadius="90dp"
      android:topRightRadius="90dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="90dp"/>
   </shape>
```

I tried to change the form with

```
android:src="@drawable/my_shape"
```

but this changes only the icon inside my button. 
I think I need to extend FloatingActionButton but I have no idea how.

Is there a way to change the shape of the fab? If someone has already achieved this I would appreciate to see a sample.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Though I found another solution, I think that the answer provided by @JediBurrell is the better approach and works just fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The FloatingActionButton provided by the support libraries can not be extended as the methods that would need to be replaced are set to private. [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components) (which is the official AndroidX replacement for the support library) has [Shape Theming](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape/) on the [roadmap](https://github.com/material-components/material-components/blob/develop/ROADMAP.md) for ~October-December, which will let you do just that officially and easily (without having to extend the view).

But it's not available just yet, so in the meantime, I forked [customFloatingActionButton](https://github.com/robertlevonyan/customFloatingActionButton) by robertlevonyan, and with some slight modifications, it allows you to use your own custom shape. The source code is available [here](https://github.com/JediBurrell/customFloatingActionButton).

To add it to your project with Gradle, you'll need to use [jitpack](https://jitpack.io). You can add it like this:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       ...
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
}
```

Then implement my fork:

```
implementation 'com.github.JediBurrell:customFloatingActionButton:-SNAPSHOT'
```

Next we'll create the shape, the one you created should work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/fab_circle_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/fab_circle_radius"
        android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/fab_circle_radius" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

Then finally add it to your layout (more FAB options are listed in the Github repo):

```
<com.jediburrell.customfab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:fabType="custom"
    app:fabShape="@drawable/fab_teardrop"
    app:fabIcon="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
    app:fabColor="@color/red" />
```

And here's how that looks:

[image]

Comment: Actually, as I've read, it should be possible now: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133389626 . https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton#setshapeappearance https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.java .Problem is, I don't see much samples and tutorials about it. Do you know how to use it?Can you please show how to make something basic like rounded corners horizontal FAB (like in contact-details screen)?

Answer (score 18):

With the Material Components Library you can use the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/fab_3_rounded"
    .../>
```

with:

```
<style name="fab_3_rounded">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to update any external library update your Gradle file from

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

this will give you access to

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then you can change its properties just like a normal button

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking for is changing the background of your button

```
android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
```

Comment: You should edit your answer to have the sample code part formatted.