# How to change shape of bottom-appbar and floating action button

Tags: android, material-design, shapes, android-bottomappbar

How can I change the shape of the android material design bottom app bar and the corresponding floating action button?
I want the floating action button to be insetted into the app bar. This is possible using the material bottom app bar. But I want the floating action button to be a rectangle instead of beeing a circle. Material design shows an example of this on their website but just as an image without explanation how to do this.
EDIT: I want to change shape not just color

Comment: I dont want to change color. I want to change shape

Comment: Sorry, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260814/how-to-change-the-shape-of-floating-action-button-fab-on-android